# _popen() in Windows does not work interactively

Tags: c++, createprocess

I am using _popen() to create a pipe to communicate with another program which I can only execute and do not have source code access to. I have tried examples given in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) (_popen example) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/190351) (CreateProcess and CreateThread example(). Note that the code is almost the same except that for _popen I have modified it to write to pipe instead as below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main( void )
    {

       char   psBuffer[128];
       FILE   *pPipe;

            /* Run DIR so that it writes its output to a pipe. Open this
             * pipe with read text attribute so that we can read it 
             * like a text file. 
             */

       if( (pPipe = _popen( "myprogram", "wt" )) == NULL )
          exit( 1 );



        /* Read pipe until end of file, or an error occurs. */

    while(!feof( pPipe)))
    {
    char cmd[32]="";       
    while(fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe))
           {
              printf(psBuffer);
           }
    scanf("%s", cmd);
    fprintf(pPipe,"%s",cmd);

    }


           /* Close pipe and print return value of pPipe. */
       if (feof( pPipe))
       {
         printf( "\nProcess returned %d\n", _pclose( pPipe ) );
       }
       else
       {
         printf( "Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
       }
    }
```

The output I expect to get is like:

```
Some Text -> from myprogram
command entered from parent
Some more Text -> from myprogram
more command from parent
..
..
```

Till myprogram terminates

However what I get is

```
Some Text -> from myprogram
command entered
```

and it keeps on accepting the commands eternally

Can you help here?

Thanks,
FC

Comment: This `printf(psBuffer);` does not look right

Comment: Didn't change it actually. Have used it as it was on MSDN, so didn't really doubt it.

Comment: `fgets` is a blocking call and reads until a newline is found, the buffer is full or the stream ends. So your inner `while` loop runs until myprogram is terminated, without ever executing the `scanf` call in the outer loop before the end. If you only expect one line of text from myprogram, you could as well get rid of the inner `while`. Otherwise you would have to find a way to tell that myprogram is finished writing and can accept input.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Okay. So even when I remove the while, `fgets` comes out (I assume) since I am getting an message which I have put at the end of outer loop. However I guess the input is not reaching the pPipe, or rather `fgets` is still blocking the pipe. I tried using `fscanf` instead, but then my input doesn't reach the pPipe.